# How to make do-while loop works for its not looping at all?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, return, do-while

I have these codes. I chose the do-while loop, so I can do the looping, but somehow it doesn't work.

So, in my database, there are at least 5 rows from the "SOALTXT" field, that have id=S01, which mean, tht it should do looping for 5 times. But somehow it only shows one row.
Like this:

not expected output:
[image: not expected output]

```
<?php
    include "koneksi.php";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM buatsoal_db ORDER BY ID DESC");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $id = $result['ID'];
    ?>

<?php
    do{ ?>
        <form method= 'post'>
        <input name='next' type='submit' id='next' value='next'>
        </form>
            <?php if(isset($_POST['next'])){ 
    >           $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
                echo $row['SOALTXT'];           
            ?>
            <br>
            <br>
            <?php           
            } 
            ?>

<?php   }
    while ($id =='S01');
?>
```

For the output, I expect 5 'next ' button, and when it clicked, show up each one 'soaltxt'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $id is not being updated inside the do while loop. Just add another

```
$id = $row['ID']
```

before the echo in the loop.

Edit:

I was going to post a new snippet but the answer from @Omar Abbas is along the lines of what I intended. I would get the form outside of the loop and add a hidden input to pass an index to the next page so you know how many times you pressed next so you know how many rows to display.

Learning to ask the right questions is important in this industry. Important parts of it are good phrasing and as few assumptions as possible.

Comment: thank you... ive added it, but, the output is totally not what i expected ,, LOL. it shows the next button first, once i clicked it, 4 more button shosw up, also with the 'soaltxt' record. i want it to be the 'soaltxt' record shows up only afte the next button i clicked. do you know how??

Comment: the $_POST['next'] will be true on the page once you click the next button, that's why the behavior you described happens.

Comment: im totally new with this, and this is my first work. do you know how to solve it?  ^o^?

Comment: @AyuHapsari `but, the output is totally not what i expected` is kinda outside the scope of your original complaint. Just saying, who's going to upvote the answer, me or you? Guess I will.

Comment: @GetSet, i've upvoted it, but it just didnt work, it keeps back to 0, and i dont know why.

Comment: @AyuHapsari I forgot about that. 50 rep pts needed or something like that for it to reflect immediately.

Comment: @GetSet only the users with more then 15 reputation vote and publicaly shows. at least i said it solve the problem. and when i said the ouput is not what i expected, it just that i laughed for myself making blunder with my first programing codes and when someone saves me, the output is totally not wht i expected it to be.

Comment: @AyuHapsari I get what you mean. Happens. One solved bug leads to another.

Comment: @GetSet yeah,, and it kills me.. LOL ^^

Comment: @AyuHapsari We've all been there, wish you luck on your journey

Comment: @GetSet yep, TRUE. ^^

Comment: @AyuHapsari Yeah seemed appropriate. Keep the laughter. At end of day its just a program.

Comment: @DanIftinca I'm still there. Got a program with bugs i dont want to look at for a month. All laid out on a to-do list.

Comment: @GetSet i think i just saw my future XD

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question you are using `mysqli_fetch_array()` find details about [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) now you also need to check on which index your `id` resides in the `$row` like `$row[0]` or whatever that index might be, and assign this value to the $id variable like `$id = $row[0]` and then put that into `while($id = 'S01')`

possible solution, only fetch the records that have `id = S01`, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and use While loop, find details [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM buatsoal_db WHERE ID=S01");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo $row['ID'];
}
```